# Is it possible to read a string with fscanf and save it as unsigned int in an unsigned int pointer?

Tags: c

Is it possible to read a string with `fscanf` and save it as `unsigned int` in an `unsigned int` pointer?
I must scan a file that contains ASCII text and save it in an `unsigned int` double pointer. It's defined as `unsigned int ** list`.

Comment: allocate appropriate space for `list`, use `fscanf` to read a string value from the file, use something like [`strtoul`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul) to convert the string to `unsigned int`, save it in the appropriate place in `list`. If you're having trouble with one of those steps, edit your question and show the code you've tried.

Comment: @yano: While I'll grant it's got issues with error-handling, why `fscanf` to string then `strtoul` instead of just `fscanf` to the `unsigned int` directly. This is clearly a homework assignment, I'm guessing they want the OP scanning directly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I was simply following lock-step with the OP, assuming that was the requirement. Certainly not opposed to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to read a string with `fscanf` and save it as `unsigned int`

Yes.  `fscanf` reads a string, but you can convert it to an `unsigned int` with, say, the standard C library `strtoul` function.

> in an `unsigned int` pointer?

No, not directly.  But you can certainly store it in a location *pointed to by* an unsigned int pointer.

> I must scan a file that contains ASCII text and save it in an `unsigned int` double pointer.

Oh, you're changing the rules!  First you said you had "an `unsigned int` pointer", now you're saying it's "an `unsigned int` double pointer"! :-)

> It's defined as `unsigned int ** list`.

There are several possibilities for how you can manage this, depending on details which you haven't specified.

1. Perhaps your caller has given you an `unsigned int` pointer that points to a single `unsigned int`, and that is pointed to by an `unsigned int` double pointer.
2. Perhaps your caller has given you an `unsigned int` pointer that points to multiple `unsigned int`, and that is pointed to by an `unsigned int` double pointer.  Ideally in this case your caller would also tell you how many of them there are.
3. Perhaps your caller expects *you* to allocate memory for one or more objects of type `unsigned int`, and then to return your pointer to this/these values via the caller's `unsigned int` double pointer (that is, "by reference").

Of these, #3 is probably the most likely.